# yii phpunit testing with views in coverage

Tags: php, unit-testing, yii, phpunit, code-coverage

My Yii app getting phpunit coverage in controllers, models, components, modules but not any views. The  problem is that code coverage loader in phpunit includes the view file during preparing a coverage report. Views with forms have calls `$this->beginWidget` which causes a crash since there is no $this context.

Views dont really have important code or logic but still they have some conditions and even loops to call `renderPartial` so it would be good to get a view code also covered.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Great question! I wish more emphasis was placed on unit and functional testing in the framework guides and books rather than the standard boilerplate functionality that you can learn in 10 minutes.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried extending [CWebTestCase](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebTestCase)? Generally when writing unit tests, you have fixtures and things to provide the necessary data - but with tests on views and 'functional' tests, for web-apps, it's generally easiest to mimic a browser and have it perform actions on the web app as if a user was actually using it. Currently, this mimicking is most easily done with Selenium (in my opinion).

The Yii Guide on [Functional Testing](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/test.functional) is a good place to start as well as the [Selenium Documentation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/). There's also [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847199585) that goes over using selenium (I'm not sure if the newest edition does, but I know the previous release with Publication Date: August 11, 2010 did), and Larry Ullman's [Yii Book](http://yii.larryullman.com/toc.php) will have chapters on testing and the usage of Selenium in functional tests when he's completed that chapter.

Hope this helps!

**Update to further explain [CWebTestCase](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebTestCase)**

CWebTestCase extends [PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.2/en/selenium.html) which directly implements a functional testing foundation that you can use within phpunit in order to test views, test widget creation inside of views, assert that text exists, 'click' on links, etc. These tests are still run from the command line though they require that Selenium-RC server be started upon the test being run and they require a valid browser being configured. A valid browser can be configured with as little code as the following placed inside of the `setUp()` function:

```
$this->setBrowser('*firefox /usr/lib/firefox/firefox-bin');
```

Stating that code coverage cannot be provided by CWebTestCase is not true, as CWebTestCase extends PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase, which provides the following as quoted from [the documentation](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.2/en/selenium.html):

> PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase can collect code coverage
>   information for tests run through Selenium:
>
> Copy `PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase/phpunit_coverage.php` into
>   your webserver's document root directory. In your webserver's php.ini
>   configuration file, configure
>
> `PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase/prepend.php` and 
>   `PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase/append.php`
>
> as the `auto_prepend_file` and `auto_append_file`, respectively. In your test
>   case class that extends `PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase`, use

`protected $coverageScriptUrl = 'http://host/phpunit_coverage.php';`

> to configure the URL for the `phpunit_coverage.php` script.

Comment: My testing is console based checking models, and actions and even doing Xpath asserts on html output. The code coverage report on views done by phpunit is the issue. Selenium too wont code cover the lines of php in views.

Comment: Please see me updated answer below - I believe CWebTestCase provides exactly what you're looking for due to its extending of `PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase`. If it does not, I don't understand your question enough and I'm sorry I couldn't be of more help.